# Проблемы с функцией getch

Tags: c++

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>.
using namespace std;
void you_must_enter_a_number(int);
int main(){
   you_must_enter_a_number(2);
   return 0;
}

void you_must_enter_a_number(int size){
   int result = 0, controller = 0;
   char* nums;
   nums = new char[size+1];
   char c;
   while((c = _getch() != '\r') && (controller < size)){
    cout << c << endl;
    nums[controller] = c;
    controller++;
    //cout << controller << endl;
   }
   nums[controller] = '\0';
   cout << atoi(nums) << endl;
}
```

Цель данного кода — посимвольно считать введенный текст с консоли, помещая каждый символ в массив символов nums. Почему-то getch считывая введенный символ, при попытке его отображения, отображаются улыбающиеся кружочки.

В чем причина?

Comment: Оно над Вами смеется.

Comment: cout << (c & 0xFF) вероятно решит проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы не советовал использовать нестандартные функции такие. как `_getch`.

Данное условие в предложении `while`

```
(c = _getch() != '\r')
```

эквивалентно следующему условию

```
(c = ( _getch() != '\r') )
```

Я думаю, что вы имели в виду

```
( ( c = _getch() ) != '\r' )
```

Следует также освободить память, выделенную под массив, адресуемый указателем `nums`:

```
delete []nums;
```